# How do I print a list of URLs to console from a webpage using Selenium chrome driver in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The big picture is to print all URLs in a specific location on a website to console.
This can give me the text to all the links, but not the URLs. please help. sorry, I'm very new to coding. I've been told to use a different web driver, but for my current project, I want to stay in Selenium.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace Test_Scraper_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Initialize chrome driver
            using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tfrrs.org/");

                //find elements
                var Search_Field = driver.FindElementByXPath(@"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/input");
                var Search_Button = driver.FindElementByXPath(@"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/button");

                var Count = 1;

                Search_Field.SendKeys("Ashley Smith");
                Search_Button.Click();

                var titles = driver.FindElementsByClassName("allRows");
                foreach (var allRows in titles)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(allRows.Text + Count++);
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `allRows` is `tr` element like below.

```
<tr class="filtered allRows ">
    <td id="col0">
        <a href="//www.tfrrs.org/athletes/3721395/Youngstown_St/Ashley__Smith_.html">Ashley  Smith </a>
    </td>

    <td id="col1">
        <a href="//www.tfrrs.org/teams/xc/OH_college_f_Youngstown_St.html">Youngstown St. (F)</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But you need `href` attribute of `a` element. So you need something like this, assuming you want first link:

```
var column0 = allRows.FindElement(By.Id("col0"));
var aElement = column0.FindElement(By.TagName("a"));
var link = aElement.GetAttribute("href");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. when I added the variables it said "allRows" doesn't exist in the code. im still un able to print a list of all the urls to console...

Comment: @StevePaternostro have you added it inside of foreach loop? Variable allRows exists there.

Answer (score 1):

Use `allRows.getAttribute("href")` instead of  `allRows.Text` in your foreach loop to get the URL

Comment: do i change it so...       Console.WriteLine(allRows.GetAttribute("href"));    This does not print anything to console :(

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Test_Scraper_1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Initialize chrome driver
        using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tfrrs.org/");

            //find elements
            var Search_Field = driver.FindElementByXPath(@"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/input");
            var Search_Button = driver.FindElementByXPath(@"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/button");

            var Count = 1;
            //Navigate to target page
            Search_Field.SendKeys("Ashley Smith");
            Search_Button.Click();

            var titles =driver.FindElementsByClassName("allRows");   // driver.FindElementByLinkText("Ashley Smith");


            foreach (var title in titles)
            {
                var Link_Name_TFRRS = title.FindElement(By.TagName("a")).GetAttribute("href"); ;    

                Console.WriteLine(Link_Name_TFRRS);
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
}
```